# Has a VPN actually logged where I've been?

Tags: privacy, vpn, social-media

I have been using Touch VPN for a few months to view social media accounts because I worried I was viewing them too much and would be flagged or something. I just learned, however, that VPNs keep logs and store info, especially when accessing social media sites, and especially the particular VPN I used. I downloaded and deleted the Touch VPN Chrome extension multiple times over the last few months. Should I be worried about the VPN doing anything with the data collected on the sites I viewed and the people knowing I viewed their accounts multiple times?

Comment: Please don't add new questions to an answered post. And no, no one here is going to know when some company will decide to delete old logs.

Comment: Unfortunately, schroeder is right, it's impossible for us to know. Depending on their jurisdiction, there could be a legal minimum - or it could be as many logs as they have storage for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are really three questions being asked here:

- Is it *possible* that my VPN provider has logged my activity?
- Is it *likely* that my VPN provider has logged my activity?
- *Has* my VPN provider logged my activity?

#### Is it possible?

The answer is a clear **yes**. From a technical perspective, it is absolutely a possibility that your VPN provider has logged this activity. They may be required by law to do so, or they may have other incentives to do so.

It should be noted that, merely because a VPN provider *claims* that they do not log user activity, there is no way for you as the customer to verify that statement.

#### Is it likely they look at me specifically?

I'd say **no**. At least, not in the sense that the VPN would be targetting *you specifically*. Judging by how many people have installed their apps, I would say they have a sizable customer base, and unless you are a politically exposed person or otherwise a high-value target, you're just one of many.

According to their privacy policy, they **do log** your IP address, what sites you visit and other things. However, logs that nobody looks at are meaningless. So what I'd be more worried about is them selling that traffic data to some third party company.

#### Do people know I have viewed their accounts?

> Should I be worried about [...] the people knowing I viewed their accounts multiple times?

Generally, social networks do not show people who viewed their profile. Social networks may tell users statistics about their posts, such as how often they have been viewed, but there is no individual breakdown of who viewed these posts.

However, the behavior you describe does seem quite compulsive (as you indicated in your question) and I would suggest you to contact a mental healthcare professional.

Comment: Privacy policy says they log your IP address, the sites you visit and for how long, unique IDs if available, and potentially more (and the VPN protocol is point-to-point tunneling)

Comment: @belkarx I didn't want to go sifting through their privacy policy. Kudos to you for actually doing that :D